# need update table raw values in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Hellow, I have a table in My DB as permission. I need update table raw. see My edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')@section('content') <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<h1 class="page-header"> Update Permission</h1>

@include('layouts.partials.alerts')
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Status</label>
            <select name="status" id="status">
                <option value="{!! $permission->status !!}">{!! $permission->status !!}</option>
                {{ getStatus($permission->status) }}
            </select>
            @if ($errors->has('status'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div></div>@stop
```

but I got this error

```
Undefined variable: permission (View: C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\c\resources\views\collaborators\edit.blade.php)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Blade uses the data you have passed from the controller, e.g return view('collaborators.edit',['permission' => $permission);.You are probably getting that error because you did not send the permission object to the view.To check put this {{dd(get_defined_vars())}} after @include('layouts.partials.alerts') that will dump all the data defined in the scope of the view check if you have the object in there.

Comment: put your code then got following screen array:6 [▼
  "__path" => "C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop\c\storage\framework\views/b94954c8c62e396520e272d2d36d536baa132a53.php"
  "__data" => array:3 [▶]
  "obLevel" => 1
  "__env" => Factory {#144 ▶}
  "app" => Application {#2 ▶}
  "errors" => ViewErrorBag {#175 ▶}
]

Comment: hey please expand the '__code' array to see the data sent to that view